# How to tell if a string is empty other than <br /> tags?

Tags: php, string, null

I have three variables that may or may not contain data.

let's call them $name, $address and $telephone.

Let's say I want to combine them all into one var, $contact, each on a separate line.

`$contact = $name.'<br />'.$address.'<br />'.$telephone;`

`$contact` then gets put into an array.  That array eventually goes through a foreach loop, not handling any vars that are equal to `''`.  How do I tell if the string is empty other than the two `<br />` tags?  I've tried copying $contact to $test_contact and running `str_replace('<br />', '', $test_contact;` but even when all the vars have been set to `''` `$test_contact == ''` still evaluates to false.  I've also tried `trim()` after `str_replace()` but that doesn't seen to work either.  I've also tried using `===` but again, no luck.

What am I missing?  Is there a better way to do this?

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check before inserting:

`if ($name.$address.$telephone == '')`

then is empty

Answer (score 2):

Going the `str_replace` route should definitely work:

```
if(trim(str_replace('<br />', '', $test_contact)) == '') {
  echo 'empty';
}
```

But why don't you check before inserting it into your array?

```
if(strlen($name) + strlen($address) + strlen($telephone) == 0) {
  // don't insert
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(strlen(str_replace("<br />", "", $test_contact)) === 0) {
  //empty
}
```